# Please turn syntax highlighting on for Software Recommendations

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes the answer to a question is a simple, *or not so simple*, batch file or script and likewise some questions include code sections to illustrate the problem. Unfortunately, unlike some other stack overflow sites, it seems that syntax highlighting is off for Software Recommendations.

I have tried adding `<!-- language-all: lang-python -->` and/or `<!-- language: lang-py -->` to the content of [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23034/software-that-can-recognize-the-paragraph-structure-of-a-scanned-handwritten-tex/23071#23071) but it still does not highlight the code sections.

Surely there would be very little overhead in having the syntax highlighting turned on and for such questions & answers there would be a big improvement in the quality of the answers as syntax highlighting add much to the clarity.

Comment: I agree, if that's an issue for someone's system requirements he probably won't find this SE useful anyway...

Answer (score 4):

Right now, [we have 865 posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/353783) using a `pre` block, out of 13362 total (that's about 6.5%). A very unscientific sample of those suggests that code here is often used for running things in the command line (which we probably don't want highlighted) or for other non-highlightables - think [AutoHotKey <sup>*</sup>](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1416/46), [input examples](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20012/46), [theoretical config files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21579/46), etc.

Again, this was unscientific and probably wrong. **If there's support for this**, the CMs want to see a list of posts that would have benefitted from it in the past, as proof that this will actually be used in real life. We can compile that list here if we want to, or make a new post for it.

---

<sup>* I'm not really sure if we can highlight AutoHotKey scripts, but my gut says we can't</sup>

Comment: Here are some answers I wrote that I wish had syntax highlighting: [#1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/38984), [#2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/41962), [#3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/42662).